# Cannot align \subfigures to the center of page properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats, subcaption, textwidth

I want to plot two graphs side by side using the \subcaption library. However, I'm having difficulty in adjusting the width of the floats which is causing them not to not be plotted side by side.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
          xlabel=$\mathcal{L}_1$,
          ylabel=$\mathcal{L}_2$]
          \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[ x index={0},y index={1}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
     \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xlabel=$\mathcal{L}_1$,
                ylabel=$R_g$]
        \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[x index={0},y index={1}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix but I'm very new to LaTeX and still learning. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the width of the plots. I would recommend making the subfigures wider.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=0.98\textwidth,
          xlabel=$\mathcal{L}_1$,
          ylabel=$\mathcal{L}_2$]
          \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[ x index={0},y index={1}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=0.98\textwidth,
                xlabel=$\mathcal{L}_1$,
                ylabel=$R_g$]
        \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[x index={0},y index={1}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a cleaned up version (almost everything from Zarko's comment below, thanks!!)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth, xlabel=$\mathcal{L}_1$}
      \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[ylabel=$\mathcal{L}_2$]
          \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[ x index={0},y index={1}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[ylabel=$R_g$]
        \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[x index={0},y index={1}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With you nor with OP code I can't reproduce showed images. Content of graphs are different. Of course, a way how to solve the problem, is correct.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! I keep forgetting that, for some for me not understandable reason, `filecontents` got changed, and `\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}...` does no longer overwrite `data.csv`, so I had an old file of this name in my directory. Fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: This confuse me so I didn't publish my solution :-(. Adding `pgpfplotsset{comapt=1.16}` to preamble and `\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth, xlabel=$\mathcal{L}_1$}` into `figure` (and delete those data from `axis`), the `ylabel`  are more nicely positioned ... This is a bit strange. Maybe because I wake-up to early :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked